# Convert array of string to array of object using es6 or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of string which I want to turn it to array of object.

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want to generate

```
array= [
  {'name': 'a', 'isChecked': false, 'availibility': 0 },
  {'name': 'b', 'isChecked': false, 'availibility': 0 },
  {'name': 'b', 'isChecked': false, 'availibility': 0 }
];
```

I tried below and still returning the originalArray!

```
array.map((name) => ({
  name,
  isChecked: false,
  availability: 0
}));
```

How would you do this?

Comment: `map` does not mutate the original array but returns a new one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` like this:

```js
array= ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let newArr = array.map(item => {
  return {
    'name': item,
    'isChecked': false,
    'availibility': 0
  }
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the following, because as @ASDFGerte pointed out, `map` does not modify the original object, but returns a new one which you should assign to a variable. In this case, I've just assigned it back to the original `array` variable.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array = array.map((name) => ({
    name,
    isChecked: false,
    availability: 0
}));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `map()` works as expected, but it does return a new array. If you want to mutate the original array, use `forEach()`

```
array.forEach((val, i) => array[i] = {
    name: val,
    isChecked: false,
    availability: 0
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Old-fashioned  way:

```
var outputArray = [];
var inputArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i=0, len = inputArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    outputArray.push({
           name : inputArray[i],
           isChecked : false,
           availability : 0
    });
}
```

If you want to use `map()` you need to store the object in new array.